# Unable to implement UILabel  using nib and IBOutlet

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, iboutlet

I have a UILabel, which I made using the nib.

To my code I have added (in the appropriate places)

```
IBOutlet UILabel *question;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *question;

@synthesize question;
```

In the nib, I have connected the label to the file's owner.

However, something like `question.text = @"test"` yields no result. Also, an NSLog showed me that (question == nil) is TRUE

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Can you describe more about how the nib is being loaded? Is the question property defined on the File's Owner class and is the nib loaded? And the label is connected to the question property of the File's Owner?

Comment: In another class I call `QuizController *quizController = [[QuizController alloc] initWithNibName:@"QuizController" bundle:nil data:data.quizQuestions]` (I overrode the initWithNibNameClass to add another variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there may be more issues that is causing this problem.
I'll list out some, may you get help

as you said, you are using your own method to construct your class

- QuizController *quizController = [[QuizController alloc] initWithNibName:@"QuizController" bundle:nil data:data.quizQuestions]

check your `initWithNibName` method again.
you have to do

```
self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
```

- check your nib file again, class of `File's Owner` is `QuizController` on `Identity Inspector`
- and in which method you are using `question.text = @"test"`. Try to assign text on `viewDidLoad` method, not on your constructor.

let me know the results

Answer (score 0):

Because the UILabel is implemented as a property, try self.question.text = @"test"

Comment: Try making the second line @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *question;